# CA1062 doesn't trigger in vs2019 net5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, code-analysis

I'm hoping to see CA1062, Validate Argument of public methods. But I'm not. It seems Code analysis is running because I see CA1822 for some items.
Here's an example of code I'm hoping would trigger CA1062.

```
public class FooController : BaseController<IFooProxy>
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("bar")]
    public async Task<bool> Bar(string baz)
    {
        bool hasXyz = baz.Contains("xyz");
        Console.WriteLine(hasXyz);
```

This is the csproj settings:

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
      <EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>
      <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
      <AnalysisLevel>preview</AnalysisLevel>
      <AnalysisMode>All</AnalysisMode>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

It's actually just a desperate attempt to turn everything on... I find myself missing the previous method, with a property page in the project to select rule set.

StyleCop is long gone, if the above doesn't work somehow, is there any open source way to run the rules?

Comment: Are you using .NET Core or .NET 5 and upwards, and if so, have you enabled nullable reference types?

Comment: It's net5, but I can't see <Nullable> in the csproj.

Comment: <Nullable>enable</Nullable> and <Nullable>warning</Nullable> does generate warnings, but not anything in this file and not CA1026.

Comment: Yes, simply enabling nullable reference types won't generate a CA1026 (as it generates it's own warnings), and also won't generate a warning in this context, as you're telling the compiler that `baz` cannot be null, if you were to properly use nullable reference types like `string? baz` then you'd get a warning akin to `baz is potentially null` on your `baz.Contains` call. Do you need the generated warning to specifically be CA1026?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/6ae50529e7b88493b2591fb533ceebadc8425e1d/src/NetAnalyzers/Core/AnalyzerReleases.Shipped.md
This table says it's disabled. Is that the reason?

Comment: @MindSwipe I just want to use an analysis tool to find all unvalidated external input, before using it/passing it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable all rules in .net 5, you should use:

```
<AnalysisLevel>5.0</AnalysisLevel>
<AnalysisMode>AllEnabledByDefault</AnalysisMode>
```

BTW in .net 6, it's:

```
<AnalysisMode>All</AnalysisMode>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#analysismode

Comment: Changing to AllEnabledByDefault does the trick!

Comment: Note that enabling all analyzers _all the time_ (instead of, say, _only_ during a build) can worsen VS's UI and input responsiveness. YMMV - especially VS2019.

Comment: At least it's a starting point. Now the analysis "works". :)
Detail configuration from here.